# How can i append string to list?

Tags: list, function, recursion, lisp, racket

I am trying to completing a school assignment where i have to write  a function which takes two arguments where the first condition is the length of the list is greater than 4 which is working,however,the problems begins with appending the a variable "s" to the list.for e,g

```
(define SOB (λ ( s L1)

                (cond
                ((string? s)
                ((list? L1) (> 4)

                            (append  s L1))))))
```

this is my code i have been trying to find ways to do this but i keep getting errors.this is input test

```
(SOB "hi" '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

and this is the error i receive

```
append: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: "hi"
```

i am new to racket and i would really appreciate some help with this

Comment: `append` is for concatenating two lists. `s` is a string, not a list.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: What is `(> 4)` supposed to mean? Shouldn't you be comparing something else with 4?

Comment: i am trying to get something like this ("hello" 1 2 3 4 5 6)

Comment: Use `cons` to return a list with a new element on the front.

Comment: Something like `(if (> (length L1) 4) ...)`?

Comment: ok thanks and how would i use cons to append the string the list

Answer (score 1):

The correct function is `cons`, not `append`. `append` is for concatenating multiple lists, but `s` is not a list.

You also need to combine all your conditions with `and`.

```
(define SOB (λ ( s L1)
  (cond
    ((and (string? s) (list? L1) (> (length L1) 4))
     (cons s L1))))
```